# How to mount android phone to computer as SD Card or in debug mode?

Tags: android, terminal, terminal-emulator

Is there any terminal emulator comand in android 2.3.x with BusyBox that will mount as SD card phone connected to PC via usb?
Is there anything for enabling debuging mode to use phone with adb?

My phone won't mount by itself. I also have superuser rights.

Comment: It's interesting that clockwork recovery mod can mount my phone in one click.

Comment: I'm using Android 2.3.7. I've installed CyanogenMod 7.1.0.1 on HTC Tattoo.  I know It's my fault )

Comment: and on you PC ? Windows or Linux ?

Comment: I'm PC user and have Windows 7

Comment: mmm...you can try installing htc sync ; it installs the drivers automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're on Mac, it should directly work. If you're on Windows, you'll have to install the drivers of your mobile phone (htc, Samsung, ...) to enable the USB interface work properly

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem until I installed the drivers for my phone on my pc.

Answer (score -1):

even when drivers are installed properly your phone may not mount as SD card.
it was my case)
i've found the sollution on xda-developers forum... you can run special command in android terminal, reboot your phone and it'll be okay) (phone must be rooted and have terminal installed)
unfortunately i've lost this link...and now i get the same issue to solve...)

well. i think i've found it)
try this link: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1800935

```
su
setprop persist.sys.usb.config mass_storage
reboot
```